# Is there a way to put copyright content in the generated js file using rollup?

Tags: rollup, rollupjs

There are options to put copyright content while generating bundle using gulp etc. Is there some support provided by rollup for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to add a [`banner`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#output-banner-output-footer-banner-footer).